# Laplace transform of hitting time and running maxima

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The problem is from the Book *Probability and Stochastics* Erhan Cinlar, Chapter VIII, 3.9.

Show that for every $p$ in $R_+$,

$\int_{R_+} e^{-pt} dM_t = \int_{R_+} da e^{-pTa}$

where $M_t$ is the running maxima of standard Brownian motion and $T_a$ is the hitting time of standard Brownian motion.
There are hints that $T_a$ is Levy thus its Laplace transform has the form $e^{-a\phi(p)}$ and we know that the expectation of $M_t$ is $\sqrt{2t/\pi}$.

My question is that what is the relationship between the left-hand side and the Laplace transform of $M_t$ or the expectation of $M_t$ and what is the relationship between the right-hand side and the Laplace transform of $T_a$. I am confused about the notations of integrals in this form.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps the relation $$P(T_a>t) = P (\sup_{s\in [0,t]}B_s < a) = P(M_t <a )$$ can be useful here.